# Handling EventNavigationArgs e with 2 different ways

Tags: c#

What i am trying is to handle e OnNavigatedTo with 2 different ways depending the page was came from till now i have this but when comes to else e.parameter stays a null string[2] from the previous handling

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
 {
  if (lastpage != null && lastpage.SourcePageType.Equals(typeof(NewHabit))) // Checking from which page came
  {
      string[] Data = new string[2];
      Data[0] = string.Empty;
      Data[1] = string.Empty;
      Data = e.Parameter as string[];
}
   else if (lastpage != null && lastpage.SourcePageType.Equals(typeof(Calendar)))
{
       HabitButtons[pos].Days = e.Parameter as int[,];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not seeing the type of `e.Parameter` isn't very helpful here... But I guess that you're trying to do an invalid cast.

> e.parameter stays a null string[2] from the previous handling

If `e.Parameters` is a parameter of the handler method, then most likely it is a new instance of the argument, not the one from the previous call (unless it's some weirdly used `ref` or `out` parameter).

All in all, if the type of `e.Parameter` is `string[]`, then you'll always get an error trying to do `e.Parameter as int[,]` and you'll have to create your array by manually parsing the data inside `e.Parameter` and creating whatever data structure you need.